# Should I ask from the OP to accept my answer while my answer is the only one and upvoted?

Tags: discussion

I have seen that many times, people asking from the OPs to accept their answer, should I do the same, there isn't other way ? I just don't like that kind of attitude. I guess that the answer would be something like: "it depends on the question" but that's fine, because I want to clarify whether is okay or not to ask by someone to accept your answer or if there is another way to do so.

Comment: Nearly sure thee is a MSE post about this, but no, asking someone to accept an answer is considered bad etiquette on SE.

Comment: `I have seen that many times, people asking from the OPs to accept their answer` I am one of those people. Although, I only do it if the OPer is a newbie to the site and if their Q history shows no accepted answers, which leads me to believe they are not aware of the checkmark ✅ and they usually comment something like "thx, it worked"

Comment: @NoSssweat Great comment, really it is. It could be an answer. Describes the problem clearly and its solution in a few lines, even if it comes in contrast with the overall philosophy.

Comment: Variation of the comment from @NoSssweat : check if the user has the "informed" badge. If they don't, then I think it makes sense to remind them with something like "Since you don't seem to have the ***informed*** badge yet, you may want to look at [this help page](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)".

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens in addion; even though, they have the badge, sometimes they forget, **[Exhibit A](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207783/best-way-to-add-edit-flag-links-to-a-node-being-displayed-inside-colorbox-node/208176?noredirect=1#comment-253952)**.

Comment: @NoSssweat : or they have other priorities (too busy doing something else (like implementing the suggestion in your answer), or they make it a cameleon question (like "ok, that helped, but now I get a WSOD, now what"), or, or, or, ... Maybe you should post a meta.drupal.SE question like "what are the typical reasons why outstanding accepts never seem to happen" (with 1 answer for each such reason ... and a real question to illustrate it). BTW: using Drupal for a Q&A site, you could implement interesting [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) logic to keep nagging them ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Stack Exchange, pressing a user to accept an answer is considered something you should not do. Also, new users cannot accept an answer without waiting 2 days (if I recall correctly); telling them to immediately accept an answer is telling them to do something the system wants them to do later.
The fact they already got an answer, and that answer is correct, doesn't mean the OP could hope for an answer with a better explanation; I would say it is in their interest not to accept answers too quickly.

I remember there was a time where the user profiles showed the perceptual of accepted answers. It was removed because the users used it to comment about users not accepting enough answers, and to stop users would push new users to accept answers.